# Adding Points to line at certain distance using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, line, vertices

USING QGIS 2.18 
This question seems to have been asked a ton with lots of options.i just need to add some points/nodes/vertex to a line at a recurring distance along that line.

There are some options for use with PostGIS ([Getting points along line at defined distance using PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107277)) as well as an idea to add buffers ([Creating points along line at varying distances using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136897)) at each distance needed, but this would not be useful on a long line.

Comment: did you try `ST_Segmentize`? it's available in *SpatiaLite*, too (no need for *PostGIS* backend).

Comment: This is not a plug in.. what is it and where may I find it?

Comment: Have a look at the Processing Toolbox Panel. There are several tools that may help, such as `points along geometry`.

Comment: Thank yo csk, now having issues with my Grass install:This algorithm cannot be run :-( 
It seems that GRASS is not correctly installed and configured in your system. Please install it before running GRASS algorithms.