# Create points along lines at defined distance in PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql

I have zero experience with PostGIS and SQL, but I'm trying to create points along the line at specific distance.
I am trying this method:
[Getting points along line at defined distance using PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107277/getting-points-along-line-at-defined-distance-using-postgis)
but I cannot create an actual point table with geometry using my line table.
I was trying something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE point_table AS    
     SELECT gid, ST_AsText((dp).geom) As wkt_geom 
         FROM (
             SELECT ST_DumpPoints(
        ST_Segmentize(
            ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 30, 15 30)',5514),
            1
        )
   ) AS dp
) AS geom from my_line;
```

But I am not successful at all. Can some of you explain to me how to do this basic task since I am a complete noob?

Comment: Does the select statement work?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately in this case, `ST_Segmentize` only *inserts vertices* into the linear component of a geometry, and only when the distance between consecutive points is longer than the given `max_segment_length` - a point dump will contain the initial vertices as well.

If that is undesirable, use a `ST_LineInterpolatePoint` sequence instead; note that *the actual issue that you are facing (apart from a few syntax issues)* is resulting from `ST_AsText`, which, quite literally, returns a *WTK* **string** (type `TEXT`) from the given `GEOMETRY` - I included the proper way to also register the new `GEOMETRY(POINT)` column in the system:

```
CREATE TABLE point_table AS ( 
  SELECT n,
         ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, LEAST(n*(<desired_distance>/ST_Length(geom)), 1.0))::GEOMETRY(POINT, <SRID>) AS geom
  FROM   <line_expression|table>
  CROSS JOIN
         Generate_Series(0, CEIL(ST_Length(geom)/<desired_distance>)::INT) AS n
);
```

Here

- `Generate_Series` creates a sequence `n` over all needed points
- the `LEAST` expression returns an incremental fraction of line length, or 1.0 for the last point

This also works for the `GEOGRAPHY` type (e.g. per `CAST`), using *meter* as unit (for `<desired_distance>`).

Note that the returned points will always contain the start point as well as the end point, even if the distance to the second last point is shorter than `<desired_distance>` - so counting lengths begins at the start point. This could easily be altered to e.g. return the point sequence spread evenly over the length of the line (i.e. having a calculated offset), or to return a fixed number of segments with calculated equal distance

Answer (score 5):

#### Using QGIS

Since you added QGIS tag to your question, you can use the very simple processing tool called **Points along geometry**.

[image: Points along geometry processing tool]

It allows you to create points along the line.

[image: points along line using QGIS]

#### Using Postgis (first attempt)

Using Postgis, you can use the query you already wrote.To make it more usable, I've created another (temporary) table with the result.

My query is:

```sql
create table outros.pointalongline as 
select (foo.dp).path[2], (foo.dp).geom 
from (select ST_DumpPoints(ST_Segmentize(geom, 500)) as dp 
from outros.curvas_isobatimetricas ci where id = 295) as foo;
```

Adding the result to QGIS (along side with the previous points created with QGIS processing tool), I got the result:

[image: points along line using Postgis]

The solution differs from QGIS. The reason is well explained by @geozelot in another answer.

#### Using Postgis (based on @geozelot answer)

Using `ST_LineInterpolatePoint`, we can get the same result.

```sql
create table outros.pointalongline4 as 
  SELECT n, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(st_linemerge(geom), LEAST(n*(500/ST_Length(geom)), 1.0))::GEOMETRY(POINT, 5016)
  FROM   outros.curvas_isobatimetricas
  CROSS JOIN
         Generate_Series(0, CEIL(ST_Length(geom)/500)::INT) AS n
  where id = 295;
```

The result is identical to QGIS.

[image]