# How can I get the closest linestring in my database to the linestring drawn by some user, following a path?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, linestring, streets

I have to take a geometry drawn by an user and return the geometry in my database that represents the drawing. I tried in PostGIS

In my database I have a column 'way' with the geometry that I want to return. The 'LINESTRING' is how I get the drawing from my API.

[image: My query]

[image: The Geometries From my Database]

[image: The Geometry Drawn by the user]

[image: The response from my query]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead post actual code, which can be copied/edited to produce an Answer.

Comment: As a golden rule of *The Internetz*, giving *The User* free will is a bad idea. Freehand drawing on maps is a prime example for that. Save yourself some trouble on the rebound and invest some dev time to introduce live nearest neighbor snapping to your network. Likewise, you can implement live map matching, if snapping is undesired. The outcome is less post-processing of highly ambiguous input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few ideas:

You can for example take a buffer around your input points and only keep roads parts fully inside the buffer (using [ST_Contains](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html)).

Unfortunately, by doing that, I think you will still have some issue with very small parts. One way to handle that is to start by first grouping your small parts into larger entities. For this kind of problem I usually group roads in linestring between intersection (by detecting the number of connections for each nodes), it make more sense to me. Then you can select those linestring using the same trick, or even using some pourcentage (you compare the length of the original linestring versus the length of the result of ST_Intersection between the linestring and the buffer).

Finally, you can also look at map-matching algorithm: you can [generate some points along your input linestring](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414181/120505) for example and use that as input for a map-matching algorithm.

A simple way to implement that with OSM would be OSRM, Graphopper or in your case maybe you can just use [valhalla on your postgis](https://gis-ops.com/map-matching-postgis-plpython/)